# Groovy 2.4.x vs Java general speed difference?

Tags: java, performance, groovy, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I could not find any information out there about the current performance of Groovy. I am trying to convince a group that it is worth using and the gains in the removal of boiler plate code and xml manipulation is worth the "performance cost".

https://dzone.com/articles/java-7-vs-groovy-21
Is the newest one I can find... I was hoping to find any tests from 2.4.x vs Java 8.

Even with the old articles I can find they are all micro speed tests.  I wish someone had a few of a small app as a whole.

Comment: As a whole, why would you expect the performance to be worse? It still runs on the JVM as byte code. It still gets JIT'd. Personally, I prefer scala - but that's just an opinion.

Comment: Good tests are hard to find.  For example, are you comparing the Groovy with invokedynamic ... or without?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch the dynamic casing can really slow it down.

Comment: @scottb  I would be fine with any examples as long as they explain what speed short cuts they did tbh.